# recurring payments for five years

Tags: wordpress, recurring

I am setting up a donation page (in WordPress) for a non-profit that has a "5 YEAR DONATION PLAN". Members pay $100 per month for 72 months.

I am attempting to use PayPal's example for recurring payments:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

<!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="alice@mystore.com">

<!-- Specify a Subscribe button. -->
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">

<!-- Identify the subscription. -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Alice's Monthly Digest">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="DIG Weekly">

<!-- Set the terms of the recurring payments. -->
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="69.95">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">

<!-- Set recurring payments to stop after 6 billing cycles. -->
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="srt" value="6">

<!-- Display the payment button. -->
<input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribe_LG.gif"
alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
<img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1"
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >
```

Here is my code, edited:

```
<!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="kcarson@basinwidefoundation.com">

<!-- Specify a Subscribe button. -->
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">

<!-- Identify the subscription. -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Sky's The Limit - Galaxy72">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="STL-G72">

<!-- Set the terms of the recurring payments. -->
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="100.00">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">

<!-- Set recurring payments to stop after 72 billing cycles. -->
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="srt" value="72">

<!-- Display the payment button. -->
<input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribe_LG.gif"
alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
<img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1"
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >
```

If I use the PayPal example, as is, the PayPal page displays exactly as it should. However, when I edit the code, with our specifics, I get this error message:
"The link you have used to enter the PayPal system is invalid. Please review the link and try again."

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is there a reason the second set of code is lacking the `<form>` tag?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the srt=72 which is not allowed . The allowed values for the srt is form 0 - 52 . Here is what docs say :

**srt    :Optional  Recurring times. Number of times that subscription payments recur. Specify an integer with a minimum value of 2 and a maximum value of 52. Valid only if you specify src="1".**

You can refer the documentation [here.](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/)

Once you set it to any value between 0- 52 , it should work fine .